# 本番環境でAction_TextでS3に画像をアップロードする際に画像が編集画面にしか表示されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, amazon-s3

本番環境下でAction_Textを活用してrich_text_areaからS3に画像をアップロードした際に編集画面からしか画像が表示されません。
ちなみにS3には画像が保存されており、file_fieldでアップロードした画像の表示はできております。
画像が編集画面でのみ表示され、本番環境で表示されないことについてどなたかご存知の方がおられましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。

ビュー（フォーム）

```
  <div class="user-form__field__title">タグ</div>
  <%= text_field_tag 'article[tag_list]', article.tag_list, class: "form-control" %>
  <div class="user-form__field__title">サムネイル</div>
  <%= f.file_field :thumbnail, direct_upload: true, accept: "thumbnail/png, thumbnail/jpeg, thumbnail/gif, thumbnail/jpg" %>
  <div class="user-form__field__title">バナー</div>
  <%= f.file_field :banner %>
  <div class="user-form__field__title">コンテンツ</div>
  <%= f.rich_text_area :body %>
  <div class="user-form__field__create">
    <%= f.submit :class=>"user-form__field__create__button" %>
  </div>
```

ビュー（Showページ）

```
      <div class="article-body__box__lead">
        <%= @article.body %>
      </div>
```

_blob.thml.erbはキャプションやギガバイト、ファイル名を非表示にしています。

```
<figure class="attachment attachment--<%= blob.representable? ? "preview" : "file" %> attachment--<%= blob.filename.extension %>">
  <% if blob.representable? %>
    <%= image_tag blob.representation(resize_to_limit: local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] : [ 1024, 768 ]) %>
  <% end %>

<%#以下キャプション非表示のためコメントアウト%>
  <%# <figcaption class="attachment__caption"> %>
    <%# <% if caption = blob.try(:caption) %> 
      <%# <%= caption %> 
    <%# <% else %> 
      <%# <span class="attachment__name"><%= blob.filename</span> %> 
      <%# <span class="attachment__size"><%= number_to_human_size blob.byte_size</span> %> 
    <%# <% end %> 
  <%# </figcaption> %>
</figure>
```

コントローラー

```
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    views = @article.views + 1
    @article.update(views: views)
  end

  private
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

自己解決できました！！
どうやらimagemagicを導入する必要があったようでした！！
ありがとうございます。